# Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Google.Android.Material

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I use the MonoGame 3.8.1.303 template to create my Android project, not the MAUI template. And I set UseMauiEssentials to true in my Android csproj file so that I can use Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.

The problem is that I cannot install the NuGet package Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545 in my Android project because I get this error:

> Version conflict detected for Xamarin.Google.Android.Material.
> Install/reference Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.6.0 directly to
> project AndroidProject to resolve this issue. AndroidProject ->
> Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies 6.0.548 -> Xamarin.Google.Android.Material
> (>= 1.6.0) AndroidProject -> Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2545 ->
> Xamarin.Google.Android.Material (>= 1.4.0.2 && < 1.5.0).

I'm nor sure if I can use Xamarin.Forms with Microsoft.Maui.Essentials together in my MonoGame Android project.

Should I install Xamarin.Google.Android.Material 1.6.0 without Xamarin.Forms or what does the error message mean?

I use Target Android version 13.0 (API level 33).

**EDIT:** I have installed Xamarin.Google.Android.Material and after that I have tried to install Xamarin.Forms but then I get a version conflict with another Xamarin package.

Comment: Why do you want to use Xamarin.Forms and MAUI Essentials together in a MonoGame? Is there any specific functionality that you need from both that requires both to be installed together?

Comment: I want to use MAUI Essentials without Xamarin.Forms but I'm not sure if it is possible in my project. I will try to replace Xamarin.Forms in my code.

Comment: Yes, okay, but what for exactly? Your MonoGame project isnt a MAUI project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm nor sure if I can use Xamarin.Forms with Microsoft.Maui.Essentials
> together in my MonoGame Android project.

We know that [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms) is a nuget for xamarin forms, and `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials`  is a part a maui. So, you cannot install them to the same app.

You should figure out whether your current app is a Xamarin Forms project or a MAUI. Then select the corresponding package according to your needs.